# Setting up a another website on a wordpress folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am setting up a website inside a wordpress installation folder.
So it's like:

```
http://mysite.com/newsite/
```

Primarily, `http://mysite.com` is a wordpress installation, now I want to set up another site**(not a wordpress website)** on that directory which is newsite,
So basically it looks like this `mysite/newsite/`

When I go to that link, it changes the URL and leads me to a page of `mysite` page. I think maybe because of the .htaccess of the wordpress installation.

How can I access on my newly setup website without being redirecting me to http://mysite.com page?

PS:
Wordpress .htaccess configuration:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Paste your htaccess as well. If on windows server paste we.config as well. There is a rule somewhere which redirects. Also check if you have index.html or default file in newsite otherwise 404 might be served by wordpress rules.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani As of now, I don't have an .htaccess on my new site but I do have an index.php in it.

Comment: I added the wordpress default .htaccess configuration on my question above. Kindly check it.

Comment: As far as i know its not your htaccess problem, for making sure first make your permalink sturcture default and check it. the possible cause may be your newsite folder name has been used as slug in post or pages. so try to change your newsite to something unique name newsite12 or you can do is check for the page slug.

Comment: @anstrangel0ver Yes, indeed, my newsite has been used as a slug! I will try to do that. Thanks :)

Comment: You can establish if permalink / .htaccess is the problem be changing the permalink structure on one or both of the sites to default (?p=1 style)